# Trouble Merging Hashes from Parameters - "undefined method to_hash"

Tags: hash, ruby-on-rails-5, query-string

I am trying to build a page that displays a list of categories. When you click on one of them, you are taken to the same page but now with a new query string of the category you just selected. You can then select another category, allowing them to stack. The URL may eventually look like this.

```ruby
http://localhost:3000/filter?categories%5B%5D=restaurant&categories%5B%5D=takeout
```

In my Rails View, I'm using a `link_to` to build these URLs. When there isn't an existing category in the query string, I simply pass the Categories symbol and a single array of the category in questions permalink. When there is an existing category, I want to insert the new category into the `request.query_parameters` categories array, and then merge it with request.query_parameters as a whole. This is so I can also have subcategories and order/sort queries in the future too.

```ruby
<% @categories.each do |category| %>

    <% if !params.has_key?(:categories) %>
        <%= link_to category.category_name, shops_path(categories: [category.permalink]) %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to category.category_name, shops_path(request.query_parameters.merge(request.query_parameters[:categories] << category.permalink)) %>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

I will then use the permalinks to search my database for Categories with matching permalinks, and display my results that match at least one of any of the categories from the query string in the URL.

Clicking on the first link creates a hash like this for request.query_parameters from the following URL.

```ruby
{"categories"=>["restaurant"]}
http://localhost:3000/filter?categories%5B%5D=restaurant
```

And I would exepct the second like to create a hash like this, from the following URL.

```ruby
{"categories"=>["restaurant","takeout"]}
http://localhost:3000/filter?categories%5B%5D=restaurant&categories%5B%5D=takeout
```

However, I recieve the following error message.

```ruby
undefined method `to_hash' for ["restaurant", "takeout"]:Array
Did you mean?  to_h

Request
Parameters:

{"categories"=>["restaurant", "takeout"]}
```

How can I get round this error?

**Edit**

Found a solution, so posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. You only need to merge an array with the key of `categories:` if you don't have one already in the `request.query_parameters` hash. If you do have that key already, you can simply append the new `category.permalink` with `+=`.

So, the solution has expanded to three conditions.

1. No parameters at all
2. Parameters, but none with the key of `categories:`
3. Parameters, with the key of `categories:`

Hopefully this will help someone else in the future!

```ruby
<% if request.query_parameters.empty? %>
    <%= link_to category.category_name, shops_path(categories: [category]) %>
<% else %>
    <% if !params.has_key?(:categories) %>
        <%= link_to category.category_name, shops_path( request.query_parameters.merge!(categories: [category])) %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to category.category_name, shops_path(request.query_parameters[:categories] += [category.permalink]) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the logs and code you have written, you are trying to merge a hash to categories array which is not the right way.

Modify the code as below:

```
<%= link_to category.category_name, shops_path(request.query_parameters[:categories] << category.permalink) %>
```

Above line will push the new categories in the categories array and when receive the query parameters in the controller the additional category will be merged in the request parameters.

Comment: Good attempt. Unfortunately that creates the URL `http://localhost:3000/filter.restaurant%2Ftakeout`. This makes me think I still need to merge the `[:categories]` array with the rest of the `request.query_parameter`.